# Is the set of strings with equal number of 010’s and 101’s regular?

Tags: regular-languages, finite-automata, pumping-lemma

Consider the language $$L = \{ w\in \{ 0, 1\}^*: \#_{010}(w) = \#_{101}(w) \}$$

Is $L$ is regular? If it is not regular, can we prove that using the pumping lemma (only with pumping down)?

Answer (score 2):

The language $L$ is not regular. One might think $L$ is regular as it is tempting to think that the number of 010s and the number of 101s in a word are dependent. Yet, as explained by @gnasher729, this is not the case because occurrences of 010 and 101 can be *far* from each other. It is a bit challenging to prove non-regularity of $L$ using the pumping lemma while restricting only to pumping down. The trick is to consider a word where the occurrences are far from each other, but not too far! so that if pumping down does not decrease the number of 010s then it would definitely increase the number of 101s.

So assume by contradiction that $L$ is regular, and let $p\geq 1$ be a pumping constant for $L$. Consider the word $w = (010)^{2p} \cdot 1\cdot (101)^{2p}\cdot 0$, its not hard to see that $|w|\geq p$, and that $w\in L$. Indeed, $\#_{010}(w) = \#_{101}(w) = 2p+1$. By the pumping lemma, $w$ can be written as $w = xyz$, where $|xy|\leq p, |y| > 0 $, and $xy^iz\in L$ for every $i\geq 0$. Note that $y$ lies somewhere in the prefix $(010)^p$ of $w$. We split into cases:

- $y$ does not contain ones: if $y = 00$, then pumping it down (or equivalently removing $y$ from $w$) decreases $\#_{010}$ by two, and $\#_{101}$ is not affected (what actually happens here is that pumping down replaces an infix of the form $"\cdots 010\cdot 010010 \cdot 010\cdots"$ with $"\cdots 010\cdot 0110 \cdot 010\cdots"$). If $y = 0$, then either $y$ is the first letter of $w$, and thus removing it decreases $\#_{010}$ by one, and does not affect $\#_{101}$, or $y$ lies between consecutive occurrences of $010$, and thus removing it does not affect $\#_{010}$, but increases $\#_{101}$ by 1 (what actually happens here is that pumping down replaces an infix of the form $"\cdots 010\cdot 010010 \cdot 010\cdots"$ with $"\cdots 010\cdot 01010 \cdot 010\cdots"$). In all cases, we have that $\#_{010}(xz) < \#_{101}(xz)$. Thus $xz\notin L$, and we've reached a contradiction.
- $y$ contains $k\geq 1$ ones: in this case, removing $y$ from the $(010)^{p}$ prefix of $w$, reduces $\#_{010}$ by at least $k$. Also, this cannot decrease $\#_{101}$ because the first occurrence of $101$ in $w$ lies right before the suffix $(101)^{2p}\cdot 0$ of $w$, and thus all occurrences of $101$ in $w$ are infixes of $z$. Hence, $\#_{010}(xz) < \#_{101}(xz)$. Thus $xz\notin L$, and we've reached a contradiction. (Note that in this case, $\#_{101}$ can actually increase after removing $y$. Also note that $\#_{010}$ can decrease by $k+2$ if for example $x$ ends with $1$ and $y$ starts and ends with $00$).

Answer (score 0):

Try writing a few words that are contained (and not) in your language. See if you can discern some structure that helps answering your question.

**Hint:** CS teachers are a devious, sadistic bunch. This might be a trick question...

Comment: We have seen something similar that is a trick question, but this seems not: $(010)^*0011(101)^*$.

Comment: @HendrikJan so what should we pump to prove it isnt regular

Answer (score 0):

Most likely not, because you could have n substrings of the form 00100 and m substrings of the form 1110111, and a finite state machine would have to check that n=m.

I’d use Myhill-Nerode. Prove that the states reached after (00100)^n and (00100)^m must be different if n != m. In the first case, the smallest number of further symbols needed to reach an accepting state is 2n+1, in the second case it is 2m+1. Pumping lemma seems much more difficult.